# Azure DevOps template depend on condition

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I use Azure DevOps Template in jobs and passing a parameter stack name to it. Have to create two jobs based on the parameters, the pipeline look like this:

```
trigger:
- main

jobs:
- template: templates/run-job.yml
  parameters:
    stackName: 'A'

- template: templates/run-job.yml
  parameters:
    stackName: 'B'
```

the issue here is I want to run second template after the first is completed

Is there any way at add depends on condition here like this:

```
- template: templates/run-job.yml
  parameters:
    stackName: 'B'
  dependsOn: A
```

Thanks in advance